# How can I transfer the value of a variable to a command within a function?

Tags: jquery, variables

actually I'm using a responsive carousel jQuery plugin (slick) for my website, which works really well.

Now I want the command 'autoplay: true' to be managed by a separate variable 'ausgabe', that depends on an the existence of an id-tag. My if-clause is already working, but I have absolutely no clue how to define 'autoplay = ausgabe'. Is this possible?

In order to make a clearer question, here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ($('#comment-preview').length != 0) {
    ausgabe = "true";
  } else {
    ausgabe = "false";
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideshow-container').slick({
      dots: true,
      speed: 500,
      (
      autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 800,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
       ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

And yes, I'm a absolute rookie.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [slick slider docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), the `autoplay` property needs to be a boolean, not a string as you're currently creating. As such you can just provide it the result of the condition you check without the need to create the `ausgabe` variable, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slideshow-container').slick({
    autoplay: $('#comment-preview').length != 0,
    // other properties...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution, it works. Unfortunately I used the wrong condition. It needs to be vice versa. How can I check whether the id-tag is not existing? Just = 0? I'm sorry.

Comment: Change `!=` to `==`

Comment: Perfect! That's it! Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new too this may be blind leading blind, but I have two thoughts on how to do this. First would be in your if statement selecting the carousel element and changing the value of "autoplay" to T/F. 
Something like this: `$('element')["autoplay"] = attr_value;` Not sure if this is would work :/

My second idea would be to make all of your options into a variable and add the autoplay attribute based on the if statement, then pass the all the options into slick.

```
let options = {..}
if (){
   options = {...options, autoplay: "true"};
}else{
   options = {...options, autoplay: "false"};
}

..    $('.slideshow-container').slick(options)
```

I'm a bit more confident in this solution. You could also pass the variable ausgabe into these, but I don't think it would be needed.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank for your help! But I decided to use the shorter solution of Rory. Less to type ;-).